# Rbind an empty vector with a non-empty one

Tags: r, rbind

I have a vector called `positive.lexicon.files` that has 3 files stored in it as its elements. (Each of the files have one column of words as its content).

```
positive.lexicon.files <- c(
  "data/lexicon.fileA.csv",
  "data/lexicon.fileB.csv",
  "data/lexicon.fileC.csv"
)

pos.lexicon <- c() #empty vector

#join the contents of each file row wise in the pos.lexicon vector
for(i in 1:length(positive.lexicon.files)){
    y <- read.csv(positive.lexicon.files[i], stringAsFactors = FALSE)
    rbind(pos.lexicon, y)
}
pos.lexicon #to try and print the contents of pos.lexicon; but does nothing in the console
```

I thought this code would allow me to iterate through the files stored in the `positive.lexicon` vector, get each one's content and store that content row wise in the `pos.lexicon` vector. So, the first however many rows in `pos.lexicon` would be the content of fileA, then the next however many rows would be the content of fileB and so on. But when I run it in RStudio, the environment variable for `pos.lexicon` still shows `null`. Is this because I am rbinding an initially empty/null vector with a non-empty one?

Comment: At a minimum you actually have to assign the output of `rbind(pos.lexicon,y)` back to `pos.lexicon`: `pos.leixcon <-
 rbind(pos.lexicon, y)`. Otherwise `post.lexicon` will always be empty for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: ... and iterating over if in a `for` loop will be "alright" for small numbers but scales poorly. I suggest something like `pos.lexicon <- do.call(rbind, lapply(positive.lexicon.files, read.csv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))` (and get it all at once).

Comment: Is `to` in `for (i to length(` a typo?

Comment: BTW: without an assignment as @Mako212 suggested, `pos.lexicon` will always be *empty*, since it is never assigned to (other than `c()`).

Comment: @Hugh yes it was, I updated it in the question.

Comment: @Mako212 I added that assignment but it gives this error now: Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names

Comment: @Anna Do the headers in each file match? `rbind` only works for data frames with the same columns (i.e. does `names(fileA) == names(fileB)`)

Comment: Did you try @r2evans' suggestion?